# Decomposition a Module into a Pure Submodule and another Submodule

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am having trouble doing the following exercise.

Let $F$ be a field and let $M$ be a finitely generated module over the polynomial ring $F[x]$. Let $N$ be a pure submodule of $M$. Then, there exists a submodule $L$ of $M$ such that $N+L = M$ and $N \cap L =0$.

By *pure*, I mean that if an element $y$ in $N$ and and element $a$ in $F$ are such that there exists an element $x$ in $M$ where $ax=y$, then there exists an element $z$ in $N$ such that $az = y$.

Answer (score 1):

I will write down some hints. Firstly, since $F$ is a field we have that $F[x]$ is PID.

Consider the following short exact sequence: $0 \longrightarrow N \overset{i}\longrightarrow M \overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} M / N \longrightarrow 0$, where $i$ is the inclusion and $\pi$ is the quotient map If this sequence splits then $M=N \oplus M/N$.

In order to find such morphism $u\colon M/N \to M$ such that it satisfies the $2$nd equivalent statement of [Splitting Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) consider $M/N$ as a finitely generated module over  the PID $F[x]$ and aplpy the [Structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) and the use purity of $N$.

Comment: If this answer does not help me let me know so i can enlighten you.